# expect with cron not as manually

Tags: ssh, cron, spawn

backup.sh  has :

```
#!/bin/bash
expect backup.exp
tr -d '\15\32' < backup.templog  >  backup.log
```

backup.exp  has next content:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
puts "----------------- [exec date +%Y.%m.%d\ %H:%M:%S] ------ exp start -----\n"
spawn ssh root@someIP2
expect "# "
    send "su - postgres\r"
expect "\$ "
    send "ls -lh db.dump.gz\r"
send exit\r
send exit\r
interact
```

when I run manually like next:

```
bash backup.sh  >>  backup.templog  2>&1
```

I get next, which I like:

```
spawn ssh root@someIP
Linux db01 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u1 x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Sep  2 11:06:02 2015 from someIP2
root@db01:~# su - postgres
postgres@db01:~$ ls -lh /var/lib/postgresql/db.dump.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres 218M Sep  2 10:39 /var/lib/postgresql/db.dump.gz
postgres@db01:~$ exit
logout
root@db01:~# exit
logout
Connection to someIP2 closed.
```

but with cron (has a line):

```
*  *   *  *  *  bash backup.sh  >>  backup.templog  2>&1
```

I get only next:

```
spawn ssh root@someIP2
Linux db01 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u1 x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Sep  2 11:04:13 2015 from someIP1
root@db01:~# su - postgres
postgres@db01:~$
```

Can I get the same with cron and manually?

Comment: can you try with `ssh -tt root@someIP2` ? Maybe there is problem with tty. Or you can try `expect "postgres@"`, since there is missing the space behind `$` in your output

Comment: @Jakuje, thank you, but it does not make any different , same result